# Pentaho report not working in openerp 7

Tags: python, report, odoo, pentaho

I have create a simple invoice report from prd designer and saved.

Now I try to print report from openerp. i created an action for this report and print. Faced this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/monod/openerp/7/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 712, in go
    (result, format) = obj.create(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
  File "/home/monod/openerp/7/addons/pentaho_reports/core.py", line 160, in create
    return report_instance.execute()
  File "/home/monod/openerp/7/addons/pentaho_reports/core.py", line 99, in execute
    return self.execute_report()
  File "/home/monod/openerp/7/addons/pentaho_reports/core.py", line 120, in execute_report
    proxy_parameter_info = proxy.report.getParameterInfo(proxy_argument)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1312, in single_request
    response.msg,
ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for localhost:8080/pentaho-reports-for-openerp: 404 Not Found>
```

Comment: Can any body now about his problem?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the url configured in your openerp parameter is not matching the url of the server report. A small report server is provided with the module - executed by the command ant runtime.

Comment: thanks for your reply christophe hanon, but how solve this problem now